# Multi-push vs. multi-map

Tags: javascript

I'm asked to get attributes collection out of an array object,

```
let a = [
    {name:'aname',age:21},
    {name:'bname',age:22},
    {name:'cname',age:23},
    {name:'dname',age:24},
    {name:'ename',age:25},
    {name:'fname',age:26},
    {name:'gname',age:27}]

// wanted
let ok = {
    names:'aname;bname;cname;dname;ename;fname;gname',
    ages:'21;22;23;24;25;26;27'
}
```

and I got 2 ways of doing it:

`alpha` just using `map` of an array:

```
// alpha
let res = {
    names:'',
    ages:''
}

res.names=a.map(iter=>iter.name).join(';')
res.ages=a.map(iter=>iter.age).join(';')
//then return res

// ========================================================
```

and `beta` just iterate the array and append each attribute in the tabulation array:

```
// beta
let res = {
    names:[],
    ages:[]
}

a.forEach(iter=>{
    res.names.push(iter.name)
    res.ages.push(iter.age)
})
// then handle res's fields
ok.names = res.names.join(';')
ok.ages = res.ages.join(';')
```

so which way should I use to get the collection? Will `alpha` get slower or faster than `beta` when the objects in `a` get lots of fields(attrs)?

Comment: Please may you ask a question which won't lead to opinionated answers? Move away from "which one is better"

Comment: Alpha is more type safe.

Comment: @ztom why is that?

Comment: The attributes of `res` are declared as strings and remain so. Imagine if the code is ever rewritten in Typescript, then beta is not advantageous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are good. I'd say it depends on your personal preference what you'd want to use.

However, It seems to me that if you are aiming for performance, the following would yield better results.

```js
let a = [
    {name:'aname',age:21},
    {name:'bname',age:22},
    {name:'cname',age:23},
    {name:'dname',age:24},
    {name:'ename',age:25},
    {name:'fname',age:26},
    {name:'gname',age:27}]
    
let ok = { names: '', ages: ''}

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
const iter = a[i]
ok.names += iter.name + ";";
ok.ages += iter.age + ";";
}

ok.names = ok.names.slice(0,-1)
ok.ages = ok.ages.slice(0,-1)

console.log(ok)
```

This apporach eliminates the need to create new arrays or joining them (join is a heavy operation). Just create the string you want and at the end of it all, remove the one extra semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that alfa is simpler and clearer for me, but I guess it is up to you...

Comment: Thank you sir, ```alpha``` was also the first came to my mind.  :)